# Setting up proxy/VPN via linux server to watch Hulu from outside US?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to get to Hulu from Canada and doing it via a SOCKS SSH tunnel does not work.  How can I set up a VPN or something else with my servers in the US to gain access to hulu?

Thanks

Comment: voting to close as no longer relevant.  should the original poster come back for it, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I find OpenVPN very easy to use (it can even be setup as a server on routers with custom firmware, like tomato) and it also has Windows client if you need it.

http://openvpn.net/

http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as.html

Answer (score 1):

For watching video, you probably need the quality of a commercial provider.

Here's is [A List of VPN Service Providers](http://filesharefreak.com/2008/10/18/total-anonymity-a-list-of-vpn-service-providers/).

The cheapest of the lot, [YourPrivateVPN](http://www.yourprivatevpn.com/?q=en), offers as its most basic offering "VPN Silver", with server location in NL & USA, speed a respectful 2000 kbps, as well as unlimited monthly transfer.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is something called a ProxyServer.  Wingate is a nice one.  What it does is redirects all http directly from their ip to your ip. basicly a relay station.  i use it all the time to watch hulu or to watch megavideo after the 72 mins are up.